How to extract clean japanese text from the pdf folder in python
This is my code
import os

import PyPDF2

# set the directory where the PDF files are located
pdf_directory = '/Users/humnerohit/Desktop/test_pdf_files'

# loop through each file in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(pdf_directory):
    if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
        # create a PDF file object
        pdf_file = open(os.path.join(pdf_directory, filename), 'rb')
        
        # create a PDF reader object
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
        
        # loop through each page in the PDF file
        text = ''
        for page_num in range(pdf_reader.numPages):
            # extract the text from the page
            page = pdf_reader.getPage(page_num)
            text += page.extractText()
        
        # close the PDF file object
        pdf_file.close()
        
        # create a text file object
        text_file = open(os.path.join(pdf_directory, filename[:-4] + '.txt'), 'w')
        
        # write the extracted text to the text file
        text_file.write(text)
        
        # close the text file object
        text_file.close()


output
gai003/gai003/gai004/gai003/gai003/gai004/gai003/gai003/gai004/gai003/gai003/gai004/gai003/gai003/gai004/gai003/gai003/gai004/gai003/gai003/gai004/gai003/gai003/gai004/gai003/gai003/gai004/gai003/gai003/gai004/gai003/gai003/gai004/gai003
಩খ຀ࢢදொͷ࠶։ൃϏϧɾαϯϓϥβớຊࣾ಩খ຀Ờͷখࢁ౻ࢢ࿠ձ௕ͱ੪౻ਗ਼ࣾ௕͕Ұ೔ỏब೚͍͋ͭ͞ͷͨΊ಩খ຀ຽใࣾΛ๚Εỏ த୔ࣾ࣍ܒ௕ͱ࠙ஊỐủத৺֗ͷ֩ళฮͱͯ͠ỏ
ޙࠓ΋ؤுΓ·͢Ứͱ๊ෛΛड़΂ͨỐ
Ӻલ࠶։ൃϏϧͱͯ͠Ұࣣࣣ۝೥ʹΦồϓϯͨ͠αϯϓϥβ͸ỏࠓ೥૑ۀೋेೋ೥໨Ố֩ςφϯτͷμΠΤồͱͷे೥ؒͷܖ໿Λऴ
͑ỏࡢ೥શؗϦχỿồΞϧͨ͠ỐҰ෦ỏςφϯτ༠க͕஗Ε͕ͨỏ͜ͷ΄ͲΊͲ͕͍ͭͨͨΊỏখࢁલࣾ௕͸ࡢ೥ेೋ݄ͷגओ૯ձͰୀ೚Λਃ͠ೖΕỐࡾ݄ࡾे೔ͷऔక໾ձͰঝೝ͞ΕͨỐ৽ࣾ௕ʹ͸ࡾ੕ͷ੪౻ਗ਼ࠪ؂໾Λબ೚Ốখࢯࢁ͸ձ௕ʹब೚ͨ͠Ố
খࢁձ௕͸ủࢥ͍ग़Λ࿩ͤ͹͖Γ͕ͳ͍Ứͱ໨ΛࡉΊủαϯϓϥβ͸మೆͷ֩Ͱͳ͚Ε͹ͳΒͳ͍Ứͱޙࠓͷళͮ͘ΓʹҙཉỐ੪౻ࣾ௕΋ủখࢁձ௕ͷԿ෼ͷҰ΋Ͱ͖ͳ͍ͱࢥ͏͕ỏैۀһʹڠྗͯ͠΋Βỳͯؤுỳ͍͖͍ͯͨỨͱܾҙΛड़΂ͨỐ଍ݩ͔Β஍ٿͷ۱
ʑ
·Ͱỏڥ؀ѱԽ͕ਂࠁͷ౓߹͍Λ૿͍ͯ͠ΔỐμΠΦΩγϯỏ ԹஆԽỏࢎੑӍỏΦκϯ૚ഁյỏੜ෺छݮগỏީؾมಈ
/gai007ỐڥࠃΛ௒͑ỏͦ͢໺Λ޿͛ͯ࣍ʑʹಥ͖෇͚ΒΕΔҟมʹỏ஍Ҭ͸Ͳ͏ཱͪ޲͔͏͔Ố͔ͭͯ͸ओʹ֐ެۀ࢈ͷࢹ؂ʹ஫ҙΛ෷͏͚ͩͩ

The text is getting extracted from the pdf and stored in the same folder as same name with .txt extension.
but it seems that the data is not getting converted into japanese text.
Expecting to get clean japanese text into text file.
code which is displaying japanese character with unwanted characters
import fitz
from mecab_text_cleaner import to_reading, to_ascii_clean



def pdf_to_text(pdf_path, txt_path):
 # Open the PDF
 pdf_document = fitz.open(pdf_path)
 
 # Create a text file to store the extracted text
 with open(txt_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
    for page_number in range(len(pdf_document)):
        page = pdf_document.load_page(page_number)
        text = page.get_text()
        text_file.write(text)
 
 # Close the PDF
 pdf_document.close()

 
# Example usage
pdf_path = "/Users/humnerohit/python_pdf_to_text/S19990401A10010001001.pdf"
txt_path = "/Users/humnerohit/python_pdf_to_text/S19990401A10010001001.txt"
pdf_to_text(pdf_path, txt_path)
print("PDF converted to text successfully!")



In addition to the above comment, this code works just fine on my machine for a random japanese text exported from LibreOffice Writer to PDF and then re-extracted with this code. So more likely that the problem is with the specific input file.

Thanks for your reply!
I am very new to programming, not getting a logic which can encode the data using utf-8. how this code will become...trying to improve this code as you said.

Thank you for your reply @KJ, how can i improve my code to get clean text from the pdf.

@KJ Thank you for your repy!
this is my task using this pdf only i need to extract text. is there any way to do this?

Thank you for your reply!
This file is confidential file so i can not share it.

@KJ is it possible to share the file personally?

PyPDF2 is deprecated and you should migrate to pypdf which received lots of improvements in the meantime.
